# Looking for failing test case to DP solution to MARTIAN on SPOJ

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve [the MARTIAN problem on SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MARTIAN/)

My algorithm is as follows:

1. Define `dp[i][j]=max` amount of minerals that can be mined in the rectangle form `0,0 to i,j`.
2. Use the recurrence

   ```
   dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j] + total amount of yeyenum
                               in the i-th row up to the j-th column,
                  dp[i][j-1] + total amount of bloggium
                               in the j-th column up to the cell i-th row)
   ```

However such an approach yields a WA (Wrong Answer). Can someone please provide me with a test case where such and approach will not work?

I am not looking for the correct algorithm just a test case where this approach fails as. I've been unable to find the bug myself.

Answer (score 3):

Try this on your code(modified from the example given):

```
4 4
0 0 10 60
1 3 10 0
4 2 1 3 
1 1 20 0
10 0 0 0
1 1 1 10
0 0 5 3
5 10 10 10
0 0
```

If you start by looking at [4][4], you'll choose Bloggium, because you can get 23 bloggium by going up, and only 22 Yeyenum from going left.  However, you're going to miss a huge amount of Yeyenum.

Using your algorithm, you'll get 23 + 22 + 7 + 14 + 10 = 76.

If you choose the large Yeyenum, you'll get 70 + 14 + 10 + 22 = 116(all Yeyenum, since the bloggium gets blocked).